# Flutter Web font missing

Tags: flutter

I am following a demo in Flutter official website and the running is good in emulator:

[image]

When I tried to run this same application in Web the console shows the following:

[image]

All text Widgets do not show the text. The console shows the following message:

[image]

I am running Windows 10. All packages are udpated to the latest version.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks for the inputs. I have tried various ways to test. The situation is re-produceable but fixable too.

Possible causes that I can think of include:

1. Virus / Firewall. When disabling such softwares and re-launch, the problem seems gone, no need to add `google-fonts` package; after re-enable virus/firewall, text also shows fine.
2. VPN. Making VPN global (instead of PAC) might help, but I can't reproduce anymore.

In general, I suspect it is a problem pertaining to my network connection in China.

Comment: Do you have this font installed on your windows? Guess is required.

Comment: Yes, Roboto font family is installed.

Comment: I think you could try add the Google fonts package to make sure the font is on the app : https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Comment: Thanks! It seems working!

Comment: Did you use the Google fonts package?